# OpenCV Function to draw Gradient Orientation Arrows

Tags: c++, opencv

Does opencv have a function that can visually depict the gradient directions of an image?

Ie, a function that draws arrows over the top to visually show which direction the gradient slope runs? Or maybe colourise the image where red = angle 0 and so on?

Below is an example of what I mean when I say "visually depict the gradient directions of an image":

[image]

I know other people have done this but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is an OpenCV function or publically available function out there.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to implement it by yourself.